# I have a trip that already plan a year ago and fully paid?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am a bit confused about this sentences.

1) As I mentioned during my induction to HR, I have a trip that already plans a year ago and fully paid so that I cannot cancel it. It would be my pleasure if you both could be my buddy for below dates.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The correct sentence is:
'I'm having a trip that was already planned a year ago' , or: 'I'm having a trip that I already planned a year ago'.